# Excel - Pull out duplicate data based on first couple of words

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a large list of banks, and have already pulled out the duplicates. I now have the problem that I have the same bank, but with different different names for them (ex. some say "Wells Fargo Bank" while another is "Wells Fargo Bank, N.A.") so the first round of taking duplicates out does not fix this. How do I just group them together. Trying to stream line knowing the principle amount I owe to each of the lenders.

Comment: I used the formula "=INDEX($A$2:$A$3000,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$3000),0,0),0))" to pull out first set of duplicates

Comment: You need to show some examples and define some rules which determine what is a "duplicate".  "Fuzzy matching" is not a simple task and requires a bit more explanation on your part.

Comment: Thanks for the response @TimWilliams, some examples of what I consider a duplicate is that some are labled  "BOKF, NA dba Bank of Oklahoma" while others are "BOKF, NA dba Bank of Texas". I would have those reduced down to just BOKF. Another example is some are inputted as  "PNC Bank, N.A" while others are "PNC Bank, National Association" and I would like these categorized as "PNC Bank". What is in common with my problem is that the first left letters of what I am trying to match together are in common.

Comment: You could try this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: For stuff like this in the past I have used vlookup to pull a reference name.  Have a list with one column of the names as they are in your data, then the second column be a cleaned up reference name.  Use the vlookup in an added column in your main data, then remove dupes based on those values.

Answer (score 0):

> based on first couple of words

The following formula will extract the first couple of words (ie up to the second space from the left) from a string in A1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1))
```

and can be copied down to suit.

It [FIND](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php)s the position for the first space and then uses that to start the search for the next (second) space. Having found that position [LEFT](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) takes just the characters up to that position.

Answer (score -1):

I think `Data` > `Text to Columns` would be easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1d1uk0wMts

If you want to group by the first 4 characters, select `Fixed Width`. Otherwise you can select `Delimited` and check Comma. Just copy the data to a new column.

Now, you can group the data in a PivotTable or select the columns and `Data` > `Remove Duplicates` and check just the column where the key values are.